# What happens to the Java stack when a StackOverflowError is thrown?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Is the stack emptied in Java when a `StackOverflowError` is thrown?

In other words, what happens to the stack if I write the following recursion:

```
public void Test()
{
    System.out.println("TEST");
    try
    {
        Test();
    }
    catch(StackOverflowError e)
    {
        Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use void keyword in a constructor.

Comment: @Jakub It's a syntactically valid method signature (not a constructor). The OP merely ignored the naming convention that method names should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @ADTC Yeah, I realised that after I wrote it. That's why naming conventions are important :)

Comment: In my experience the app will come down hard.  (The JVM reserves some stack for handling StackOverflow, but once that reserved stack is used up there is nothing the JVM can do other than commit Hoot Gibson.

Answer (score 1):

`Test()` method in catch block throws another `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: it should be StackOverflowError

Answer (score 1):

This raises a lot of StockOverflowErrors! Assuming the maximumstack depth your configuration supports is 1000 calls, then this throw 2^1000 exceptions! Each call to Test() calls the Test() functions once in the try clause and once in the catch clause, so it is an exponential number of Errors that are thrown (and catched), until the final one is delegated to the top.

But to answer your question in the titel: The stack is discarded, up to the function that catches your exception.

Comment: Wrong! It's not 1000^2, but rather 2^1000. Hence this code is really just a glorified while(true) with flow control via exception capture, since even with a 128-element stack this would be executed for years

Comment: @Ordous: Correct! I update the answer to reflect your finding :).